# Generating Uniformly Distributed Random Numbers

Tags: c#, random, mathematics

**Edit:** Dunno what PCG is and don't want to read the paper? Maybe [this video](https://youtu.be/45Oet5qjlms) of Melissa O'Neill (the author) explaining things will be palatable instead.

**Original:** I attempted to answer [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/160881/11321) last week and was thrown off when someone mentioned in a comment that my method would show bias. Eager to prove the naysayer wrong I discovered that things were even worse than he suggested as certain ranges will cause things to break down entirely. So I decided to start from scratch, do some more research, and try again.

Performance was also much more important to me this time around so I decided to try and find a way to avoid calling `RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes()` to generate every single value. Eventually I settled on [PCG](http://www.pcg-random.org/) as an appropriate modern algorithm. Floating point math has also been entirely avoided while working with integers in order to avoid the sorts of issues I encountered in my previous attempts.

Looking for potential ways to speed things up or simplify the code; the branch statements bother me quite a bit but can't envision a better way to include the full range of values without them (the upper bound cannot be generated by the`GetUInt32(uint ExclusiveHigh)` method). Haven't been able to find any bugs so far but that doesn't mean they're not lurking either...

```
public class PcgRandom
{
    private const double INVERSE_32_BIT = 2.32830643653869628906e-010d;
    private const double INVERSE_52_BIT = 2.22044604925031308085e-016d;

    private static RandomNumberGenerator Rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

    private ulong m_state;
    private ulong m_stream;

    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public PcgRandom(ulong state, ulong stream) {
        m_state = state;
        m_stream = (stream | 1UL);
    }
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public PcgRandom(ulong state) : this(state, GetSeed()) { }
    public PcgRandom() : this(GetSeed(), GetSeed()) { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generates a uniformly distributed double between the range (0, 1).
    /// </summary>
    public double GetDouble() {
        return CreateDouble(GetInt32(), GetInt32());
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Generates a uniformly distributed 32-bit signed integer between the range of int.MaxValue and int.MinValue.
    /// </summary>
    public int GetInt32() {
        return ((int)GetUInt32());
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Generates a uniformly distributed 32-bit signed integer between the range [min, max].
    /// </summary>
    public int GetInt32(int x, int y) {
        var min = Math.Min(x, y);
        var max = Math.Max(x, y);
        var range = (max + 1L - min);

        if (uint.MaxValue > range) {
            return ((int)(GetUInt32((uint)range) + min));
        }
        else {
            return GetInt32();
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Generates a uniformly distributed 32-bit unsigned integer between the range of uint.MaxValue and uint.MinValue.
    /// </summary>
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public uint GetUInt32() {
        return Pcg32(ref m_state, m_stream);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Generates a uniformly distributed 32-bit unsigned integer between the range [min, max].
    /// </summary>
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public uint GetUInt32(uint x, uint y) {
        var min = Math.Min(x, y);
        var max = Math.Max(x, y);
        var range = (max + 1UL - min);

        if (uint.MaxValue > range) {
            return (GetUInt32((uint)range) + min);
        }
        else {
            return GetUInt32();
        }
    }

    private uint GetUInt32(uint exclusiveHigh) {
        var threshold = ((uint)((0x100000000UL - exclusiveHigh) % exclusiveHigh));
        var sample = GetUInt32();

        while (sample < threshold) {
            sample = GetUInt32();
        }

        return (sample % exclusiveHigh);
    }

    private static double CreateDouble(int x, int y) {
        // reference: https://www.doornik.com/research/randomdouble.pdf
        return (0.5d + (INVERSE_52_BIT / 2) + (x * INVERSE_32_BIT) + ((y & 0x000FFFFF) * INVERSE_52_BIT));
    }
    private static ulong GetSeed() {
        var buffer = new byte[sizeof(ulong)];

        Rng.GetBytes(buffer);

        return BitConverter.ToUInt64(buffer, 0);
    }
    private static uint Pcg32(ref ulong state, ulong stream) {
        // reference: http://www.pcg-random.org/paper.html
        state = unchecked(state * 6364136223846793005UL + stream);

        return RotateRight((uint)(((state >> 18) ^ state) >> 27), (int)(state >> 59));
    }
    private static uint RotateRight(uint value, int count) {
        return ((value >> count) | (value << ((-count) & 31)));
    }
}
```

---

**Distribution Results:**

[image]

**Distribution Code:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var results = Sample(2000000000);

        for (var i = 0; i < results.Length; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine($"    N: {i} | Count: {results[i]}");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static int[] Sample(int count) {
        var pcg = new PcgRandom();
        var results = new int[10];

        Parallel.For(0, count, (index) => {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref results[pcg.GetInt32(0, 9)]);
        });

        return results;
    }
}
```

---

**Benchmark.NET Results:**

[image]

**Benchmark.NET Code:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<RandomComparison>();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class RandomComparison
{
    private static Random m_random = new Random();
    private static PcgRandom m_pcg = new PcgRandom();

    [Benchmark()]
    public double DotNetRandom_Double() {
        return m_random.NextDouble();
    }
    [Benchmark()]
    public int DotNetRandom_Int32_RangeMax() {
        return m_random.Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);
    }
    [Benchmark()]
    public int DotNetRandom_Int32_RangeHalf() {
        return m_random.Next(0, int.MaxValue);
    }
    [Benchmark()]
    public double PcgRandom_Double() {
        return m_pcg.GetDouble();
    }
    [Benchmark()]
    public int PcgRandom_Int32_RangeMax() {
        return m_pcg.GetInt32();
    }
    [Benchmark()]
    public int PcgRandom_Int32_RangeHalf() {
        return m_pcg.GetInt32(0, int.MaxValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not wrong `m_stream` may be `readonly`. There are few chances that compiler will optimize code because of this but it's - as usual - more about communication than performance.

You can add one empty line after each constructors and also move `{ }` to their own line(s), it increase readability and hard-disk storage is cheap:

```
[CLSCompliant(false)]
public PcgRandom(ulong state, ulong stream) {
    m_state = state;
    m_stream = (stream | 1UL);
}

[CLSCompliant(false)]
public PcgRandom(ulong state)
    : this(state, GetSeed()) { 
}

public PcgRandom()
    : this(GetSeed(), GetSeed()) {
}
```

I see you're using `CLSCompliant` attribute. If you really care about other .NET languages without unsigned integers support then you may want to add a specific constructor just for them:

```
public PcgRandom(int state, int stream) {
    checked {
        m_state = (ulong)state;
        m_stream = stream ¦ 1;
    }
}
```

Performance shouldn't be an issue while creating the object then I'm explicitly asking for a checked conversion.

In `GetUInt32(int, int)` you need to cast range to `uint` just because you're using `+ 1UL`, just change `+ 1UL` to `+ 1`.) Also `else` after a `return` is usually redundant. For unsigned numbers overflow should do the job. Let's also see the similar `GetInt32()`:

```
public int GetInt32(int x, int y) {
    var min = Math.Min(x, y);
    var max = Math.Max(x, y);
    var range = max + 1 - min;

    if (uint.MaxValue != range) 
        return (int)(GetUInt32((uint)range) + min);

    return GetInt32();
}
```

If you're *really* looking for performance then you should avoid those calls to `Math.Min()` and `Math.Max()`. You may be surprised about branchless code JIT compiler may generate (when `CMOV` & *friends* are supported):

```
int min = x, max = y;
if (min > max) {
    min = y;
    max = x;
}
```

Or maybe even:

```
int min = x < y ? x : y;
int max = x < y ? y : x;
```

Unfortunately benchmarking this can be tricky because generated code might be different for different CPUs. Just try all of them and pick the easier one to read...What about `Math.Abs()`? Given that:

$$
|a-b| = \max(a,b) - \min(a,b)
$$

And that compiler is pretty good to avoid branches we may also want to try performance of this (pseudo-code without casts and only for full range):

```
public int GetInt32(int x, int y) {
    return GetUInt32(Math.Abs(x - y + 1)) + Math.Min(x, y);
}
```

You may also try to replace `Math.Min()` with the *usual* `(x < y ? x : y)`.

Comment: `(m_stream | 1)` isn't a micro-optimization, it's there to guarantee that the value is odd; a requirement of the PCG construction. Though, this probably means that I should make that particular constructor `private` since a user might be surprised that all even streams give the same result as the next odd stream. The only reason I didn't mark `m_stream` as `readonly` is because I eventually want to expose the stream functionality to end users but haven't figured out how to do so in a way that hides the implementation details.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but the `GetUInt32(uint x, uint y)`requires the cast to `ulong` in order to prevent integer wraparound in the case where `uint.MinValue` and `uint.MaxValue` are passed as arguments. Though, I suppose there's probably a way to allow the wraparound and still get the same results if I change the `if`...

Comment: True about odd number, I didn't do my homework! Casting should not matter for an unchecked operation (it will just overflow) but I already turned off my brain then...